# postgres fails when mounting to local folder on windows

Tags: postgresql, docker

```
docker run -it --rm 
   -v c:/Projects/docker/mcp:/var/lib/postgresql/data 
   -p 5432:5432 
   -e 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres' postgres:10.5-alpine
```

I get this output:

```
syncing data to disk ... initdb: could not fsync file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1": Invalid argument
initdb: could not fsync file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/base/13014": Invalid argument
initdb: could not fsync file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/base/13015": Invalid argument
```

I cannot find a workaround that actually works.
How do I mount the image in such a way as to preserve all the data in a windows directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible due to differences between windows and linux. The issue is particularly prominent for Postgres.

A regular volume resolves the problem, and is the best way to solve it. Mounted volumes don't work.